# Eclipse - Como negar acesso de compilação/build para usuários específicos

Tags: eclipse, compilação, team-foundation-server, active-directory, build

Boa tarde!

Estamos utilizando aqui na empresa o `Eclipse` com Integração ao `TFS (Team Foundation Server)` para fazer versionamento de arquivos. Porém, precisamos controlar também quais usuários terão acesso para compilar os arquivos (o que não é possível fazer através do plugin de versionamento... embora a ideia seja similar)

@A ideia principal que queremos adicionar no `Eclipse` é de que o usuário não possa realizar a compilação caso o arquivo não seja a última versão disponível no servidor do `TFS`.

Há alguma maneira de controlar os usuários (preferencialmente, do Active Directory) que estão aptos a usar compilação de arquivos específicos?